# SEPMC fail connection

Tags: windows-server-2008, symantec, symantec-endpoint-protection

Our Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager have stopped working. I get error that the server can't be found.
It's a single server installation where we RDP in and use the Symantec Console local on the server. But for some reason we can't connect with the manager end.

In under Services I can see that the embedded database is up and running. And I've checked ports in the config and also checked if that port is used already, but as we have always used the same port and this stopped working just a day ago.

I've tried repairing the installation. Tried restart database. Tried windows restart. Tried reconfigure after a backup of it. I can't see where everything went south...

I feel I don't get much out of the logs, this is from catalina.out:

```
2013/06/18 20:41:52:348 : Thread-19 : [com.creamtec.ajaxswing.core.ClientAgentFactory$1] Exception while warming up client agent for applicaton sepm (Exception java.rmi.ConnectException, Connection refused to host: 10.201.1.150; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect)
2013/06/18 20:41:52:363 : [com.creamtec.ajaxswing.core.ClientAgentFactory$1] Exception while warming up client agent for applicaton sepm
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.201.1.150; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:110)
    at com.creamtec.ajaxswing.ClientAgentImpl_Stub.ping(Unknown Source)
    at com.creamtec.ajaxswing.core.ClientAgentFactory$1.run(ClientAgentFactory.java:173)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:469)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:180)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:22)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:128)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:595)
    ... 5 more
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.201.1.150; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:110)
    at com.creamtec.ajaxswing.ClientAgentImpl_Stub.ping(Unknown Source)
    at com.creamtec.ajaxswing.core.ClientAgentFactory$1.run(ClientAgentFactory.java:173)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:469)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:180)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:22)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:128)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:595)
    ... 5 more
Forced shutdown monitor activated, will shutdown in 5 seconds
```

And this is from scm-server-0.log:

```
2013-06-17 03:32:29.117 ALLVARLIG: ================== Server Environment ===================
2013-06-17 03:32:29.135 ALLVARLIG: os.name = Windows Server 2008
2013-06-17 03:32:29.136 ALLVARLIG: os.version = 6.1
2013-06-17 03:32:29.137 ALLVARLIG: os.arch = x86
2013-06-17 03:32:29.137 ALLVARLIG: java.version = 1.6.0_14
2013-06-17 03:32:29.138 ALLVARLIG: java.vendor = Sun Microsystems Inc.
2013-06-17 03:32:29.138 ALLVARLIG: java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM
2013-06-17 03:32:29.182 ALLVARLIG: java.vm.version = 14.0-b16
2013-06-17 03:32:29.183 ALLVARLIG: java.home = E:\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager\jdk\jre
2013-06-17 03:32:29.184 ALLVARLIG: catalina.home = E:\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager\tomcat
2013-06-17 03:32:29.184 ALLVARLIG: java.user = null
2013-06-17 03:32:29.185 ALLVARLIG: user.language = sv
2013-06-17 03:32:29.185 ALLVARLIG: user.country = SE
2013-06-17 03:32:29.186 ALLVARLIG: scm.server.version = 11.0.6300.803
2013-06-17 03:32:36.517 ALLVARLIG: ================== StartClientTransport ===================
2013-06-17 03:32:37.930 ALLVARLIG: Schedule is started!
2013-06-17 14:54:59.557 ALLVARLIG: Broken content link detected! Skipping content: {E1A6B4FF-6873-4200-B6F6-04C13BF38CF3} Revision: 130603004 Reference Type: ObjReference ID: A869A0598E621E2A28241DB90101D2CE
2013-06-17 14:54:59.562 ALLVARLIG: Broken content link detected! Skipping content: {E5A3EBEE-D580-421e-86DF-54C0B3739522} Revision: 130603004 Reference Type: ObjReference ID: 15EB0DB73C1F34A82A95B5B4D3570E61
2013-06-18 20:41:51.556 ALLVARLIG: Unknown Exception
java.sql.SQLException: JZ006: Caught IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseError(ErrorMessage.java:557)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseErrorCheckDead(ErrorMessage.java:861)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.tds.Tds.handleIOE(Tds.java:3967)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.tds.Tds.handleIOE(Tds.java:3912)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.tds.Tds.login(Tds.java:440)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection.tryLogin(SybConnection.java:254)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection.regularConnect(SybConnection.java:230)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection.<init>(SybConnection.java:200)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection.<init>(SybConnection.java:134)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver.connect(SybDriver.java:179)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:294)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:974)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.db.util.DatabaseUtilities.getDefaultDatabaseConnection(DatabaseUtilities.java:285)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.db.util.DatabaseUtilities.getDefaultDatabaseConnection(DatabaseUtilities.java:276)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.util.logging.DbLogHandler.publish(DbLogHandler.java:74)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:458)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.util.ServerLogger.log(ServerLogger.java:293)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.util.ServerLogger.log(ServerLogger.java:274)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.servlet.StartupServlet.destroy(StartupServlet.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unload(StandardWrapper.java:1064)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.stop(StandardWrapper.java:1289)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:996)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.stop(ContextConfig.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:3757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:996)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostDeployer.remove(StandardHostDeployer.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.remove(StandardHost.java:811)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:828)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:337)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1181)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:2248)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.execute(Catalina.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.process(Catalina.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:151)
2013-06-18 20:41:51.558 ALLVARLIG: Unknown Exception during logging
java.sql.SQLException: JZ006: Caught IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseError(ErrorMessage.java:557)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseErrorCheckDead(ErrorMessage.java:861)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.tds.Tds.handleIOE(Tds.java:3967)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.tds.Tds.handleIOE(Tds.java:3912)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.tds.Tds.login(Tds.java:440)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection.tryLogin(SybConnection.java:254)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection.regularConnect(SybConnection.java:230)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection.<init>(SybConnection.java:200)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection.<init>(SybConnection.java:134)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver.connect(SybDriver.java:179)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:294)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:974)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.db.util.DatabaseUtilities.getDefaultDatabaseConnection(DatabaseUtilities.java:285)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.db.util.DatabaseUtilities.getDefaultDatabaseConnection(DatabaseUtilities.java:276)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.util.logging.DbLogHandler.publish(DbLogHandler.java:74)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:458)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.util.ServerLogger.log(ServerLogger.java:293)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.util.ServerLogger.log(ServerLogger.java:274)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.servlet.StartupServlet.destroy(StartupServlet.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unload(StandardWrapper.java:1064)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.stop(StandardWrapper.java:1289)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:996)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.stop(ContextConfig.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:3757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:996)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostDeployer.remove(StandardHostDeployer.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.remove(StandardHost.java:811)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:828)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:337)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1181)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:2248)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.execute(Catalina.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.process(Catalina.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:151)
2013-06-18 20:41:52.566 ALLVARLIG: Unknown Exception
java.sql.SQLException: JZ006: Caught IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseError(ErrorMessage.java:557)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseErrorCheckDead(ErrorMessage.java:861)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.tds.Tds.handleIOE(Tds.java:3967)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.tds.Tds.handleIOE(Tds.java:3912)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.tds.Tds.login(Tds.java:440)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection.tryLogin(SybConnection.java:254)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection.regularConnect(SybConnection.java:230)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection.<init>(SybConnection.java:200)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection.<init>(SybConnection.java:134)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver.connect(SybDriver.java:179)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:294)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:974)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.db.util.DatabaseUtilities.getDefaultDatabaseConnection(DatabaseUtilities.java:285)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.db.util.DatabaseUtilities.getDefaultDatabaseConnection(DatabaseUtilities.java:276)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.metadata.MetadataManager.getConnectionNoCheckRequireTransactionId(MetadataManager.java:903)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.metadata.MetadataManager.getConnection(MetadataManager.java:876)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.metadata.MetadataManager.getConnection(MetadataManager.java:911)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.metadata.MetadataManager.getStateMetadata(MetadataManager.java:923)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.metadata.MetadataManager.getStateMetadata(MetadataManager.java:215)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.configmanager.ConfigManager.getStateObject(ConfigManager.java:1030)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.configmanager.ConfigManager.getSemServerStateObject(ConfigManager.java:3098)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.servlet.StartupServlet.destroy(StartupServlet.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unload(StandardWrapper.java:1064)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.stop(StandardWrapper.java:1289)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:996)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.stop(ContextConfig.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:3757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:996)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostDeployer.remove(StandardHostDeployer.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.remove(StandardHost.java:811)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:828)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:337)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1181)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:2248)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.execute(Catalina.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.process(Catalina.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:151)
2013-06-18 20:41:52.566 ALLVARLIG: Unexpected server error.
com.sygate.scm.server.metadata.MetadataException: 
    at com.sygate.scm.server.metadata.MetadataManager.getConnectionNoCheckRequireTransactionId(MetadataManager.java:905)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.metadata.MetadataManager.getConnection(MetadataManager.java:876)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.metadata.MetadataManager.getConnection(MetadataManager.java:911)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.metadata.MetadataManager.getStateMetadata(MetadataManager.java:923)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.metadata.MetadataManager.getStateMetadata(MetadataManager.java:215)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.configmanager.ConfigManager.getStateObject(ConfigManager.java:1030)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.configmanager.ConfigManager.getSemServerStateObject(ConfigManager.java:3098)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.servlet.StartupServlet.destroy(StartupServlet.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unload(StandardWrapper.java:1064)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.stop(StandardWrapper.java:1289)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:996)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.stop(ContextConfig.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:3757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:996)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostDeployer.remove(StandardHostDeployer.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.remove(StandardHost.java:811)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:828)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:337)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1181)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:2248)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.execute(Catalina.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.process(Catalina.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:151)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: JZ006: Caught IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseError(ErrorMessage.java:557)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseErrorCheckDead(ErrorMessage.java:861)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.tds.Tds.handleIOE(Tds.java:3967)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.tds.Tds.handleIOE(Tds.java:3912)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.tds.Tds.login(Tds.java:440)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection.tryLogin(SybConnection.java:254)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection.regularConnect(SybConnection.java:230)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection.<init>(SybConnection.java:200)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection.<init>(SybConnection.java:134)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver.connect(SybDriver.java:179)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:294)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:974)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.db.util.DatabaseUtilities.getDefaultDatabaseConnection(DatabaseUtilities.java:285)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.db.util.DatabaseUtilities.getDefaultDatabaseConnection(DatabaseUtilities.java:276)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.metadata.MetadataManager.getConnectionNoCheckRequireTransactionId(MetadataManager.java:903)
    ... 33 more
com.sygate.scm.server.util.ServerException: Unexpected server error.
    at com.sygate.scm.server.configmanager.ConfigManager.getStateObject(ConfigManager.java:1044)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.configmanager.ConfigManager.getSemServerStateObject(ConfigManager.java:3098)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.servlet.StartupServlet.destroy(StartupServlet.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unload(StandardWrapper.java:1064)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.stop(StandardWrapper.java:1289)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:996)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.stop(ContextConfig.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:3757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:996)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostDeployer.remove(StandardHostDeployer.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.remove(StandardHost.java:811)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeployApps(HostConfig.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.stop(HostConfig.java:828)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:337)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1181)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stop(ContainerBase.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:2248)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.execute(Catalina.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.process(Catalina.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:151)
Caused by: com.sygate.scm.server.metadata.MetadataException: 
    at com.sygate.scm.server.metadata.MetadataManager.getConnectionNoCheckRequireTransactionId(MetadataManager.java:905)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.metadata.MetadataManager.getConnection(MetadataManager.java:876)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.metadata.MetadataManager.getConnection(MetadataManager.java:911)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.metadata.MetadataManager.getStateMetadata(MetadataManager.java:923)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.metadata.MetadataManager.getStateMetadata(MetadataManager.java:215)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.configmanager.ConfigManager.getStateObject(ConfigManager.java:1030)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: JZ006: Caught IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseError(ErrorMessage.java:557)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseErrorCheckDead(ErrorMessage.java:861)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.tds.Tds.handleIOE(Tds.java:3967)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.tds.Tds.handleIOE(Tds.java:3912)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.tds.Tds.login(Tds.java:440)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection.tryLogin(SybConnection.java:254)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection.regularConnect(SybConnection.java:230)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection.<init>(SybConnection.java:200)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybConnection.<init>(SybConnection.java:134)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver.connect(SybDriver.java:179)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:294)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:974)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.db.util.DatabaseUtilities.getDefaultDatabaseConnection(DatabaseUtilities.java:285)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.db.util.DatabaseUtilities.getDefaultDatabaseConnection(DatabaseUtilities.java:276)
    at com.sygate.scm.server.metadata.MetadataManager.getConnectionNoCheckRequireTransactionId(MetadataManager.java:903)
    ... 33 more
2013-06-18 20:41:52.566 ALLVARLIG: Schedule is stopped!
```

Anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: The Console is throwing a "Can not connect to management server" error. The Management server is throwing a "Cannot connect to SQL" error... Either SQL isn't running, the mgmt server isn't looking for SQL in the right place, or there's something else interfering with their communication. Sorry, don't know Symantec products anymore.

Comment: Yea, according to ODBC the SQL is up connection test was ok. When I do a netstat I can see that the database is listening on the port as usually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently running SEPM 11.0.6300.803

Upon checking the logs, we see:

```
2013-06-17 14:54:59.557 ALLVARLIG: Broken content link detected! Skipping content: {E1A6B4FF-6873-4200-B6F6-04C13BF38CF3} Revision: 130603004 Reference Type: ObjReference ID: A869A0598E621E2A28241DB90101D2CE
2013-06-17 14:54:59.562 ALLVARLIG: Broken content link detected! Skipping content: {E5A3EBEE-D580-421e-86DF-54C0B3739522} Revision: 130603004 Reference Type: ObjReference ID: 15EB0DB73C1F34A82A95B5B4D3570E61
2013-06-18 20:41:51.556 ALLVARLIG: Unknown Exception
java.sql.SQLException: JZ006: Caught IOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseError(ErrorMessage.java:557)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.ErrorMessage.raiseErrorCheckDead(ErrorMessage.java:861)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.tds.Tds.handleIOE(Tds.java:3967)
    at com.sybase.jdbc2.tds.Tds.handleIOE(Tds.java:3912)
```

When taking an RDP, make sure you are in Console mode (Session Id: 0)

Make sure you have enough disk space on the server machine.

Run the manger configuraiton wizard from start > Programs > Symantec End Point Manager > Symantec End Point Manager Tools> Manger congiguration wizard.

Add loop back address to C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc add 127.0.0.1 at the bottom of the host file.

I would suggest you to check this Article:

["Unexpected error occured" When trying to login to Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager](http://www.symantec.com/docs/TECH142451)